# Dear mods, what should be our protocol for tag burnination?

Tags: discussion, moderation, tag-deletion

There is this Meta thread: [Tag-candidates for removal](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3031/tag-candidates-for-removal). During the last <strike>three</strike> six months, it collected 8 answers with up to +12 upvotes. However, not *a single* action has so far been taken.

As burninating is something that can only be implemented by moderators (via contacting SE admin team), I would like to ask their opinions on how this process should work. What should be the rough criteria on when a suggestion gets "approved"?

---

**Update (Sep 27)**

I am bumping this thread, hoping to get an answer from one of the mods.

In the comments, @whuber pointed out that when a tag deletion seems appropriate, one of the first steps should be to edit the tag wiki excerpt to steer people away from using this tag. So e.g. the tag wiki excerpt for [dataframe](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dataframe) (35 questions, [12 votes for deletion](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3032/28666)) now says:

> This tag is deprecated. DO NOT USE IT. Use [r] instead.

The question remains as to what to do after that. If the mods prefer that any such tag should be deleted manually like e.g. `[best-practices]` [recently was](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2804), I would ask them to explicitly say so.

Comment: The answer at http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/166924 looks particularly helpful: it explicitly outlines the steps.  "Approval" is the last (and easiest).

Comment: @whuber I have seen that answer. It suggests that most burninate requests (presumably on SO) are simply bad suggestions. I am not sure this applies to our suggestions: we don't have many of them, not a single one (!) has been downvoted, and almost none has been disputed in comments. However, if you think some (or all) of our suggestions are bad, please say so! Next, the answer you linked to says that the edges should be cleaned up. This makes sense but I think at least in most cases has been done.

Comment: I was almost put off by the claim that these requests are bad suggestions--which is not something I am intimating--but I kept reading.  The rest of the post outlines a process the *community* can follow to fix up posts with tags-to-be-burninated.  It's not just closing or answering some questions, but also retagging some and possibly improving others.  One of the very first things to consider is creating or improving the tag wikis so that they steer people away from use of a deprecated tag. A quick spot check suggests there is a lot that still could be done.

Comment: @whuber (Sorry for the delay in replying) I think I am not sure I understand exactly what you mean. Let's take the two top-voted suggestions in the linked thread: [statistical] (53) and [dataframe] (39). The first has no wiki excerpt, the second does. You suggest to add/edit the excerpts so that they mention that the tag is deprecated. I can certainly do it, but I don't see how it brings us closer to the resolution of the issue. Other suggestion in your linked thread is to manually remove the tags from all threads. Is it something you'd prefer (over burninating) in these cases?

Comment: Following @amoeba's comment: it can be done, but this will make us "bump up" multiple questions (e.g. 50 R questions after removing `data.frame` tag -- I see no point in bumping them, since they are rather off-topic using current standards on CV...)

Comment: @whuber As a follow-up to my above comment, I have now provided tag wiki excerpts for [tag:statistical] and [tag:dataframe] steering people away from these tags. How do you think we should proceed in these two specific cases?

Comment: Apart from the labour of doing it slowly over time presumably we could gradually remove the offending tags by hand? Or does that not solve the problem?

Comment: @mdewey: This is clearly one possible solution. Another solution is for mods to let the tag be burninated. My question is what is the preferred solution and why. The downsides of manual deleting are: (1) considerable amount of effort, (2) long time needed to implement a full deletion, (3) regular spamming of the front page with bumped old threads.

Comment: I think this thread would still benefit from an answer; I'm unclear on what the consensus is.